# Vue TypeError: Cannot read property 'loggedIn' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Based from the error, the problem is that the getters didn't retrieve any data. I tried to change the import for store since it was setup as a default by Quasar, but it only made things worse and I tried to debug those errors for hours too. Also tried changing the default export of store and router but it's pointless since they also have built in setup from Quasar too.

Login.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <q-page>
      <h5>Login Page</h5>
      <q-input name="user" v-model="username" filled label="Username" />
      <q-input name="pass" v-model="password" filled label="Password" />
      <q-btn @click="login" label="Login" />
      <li v-if="!loggedIn">
        <router-link to="/register">Register</router-link>
      </li>
    </q-page>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapMutations } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "login",
  data() {
    return {
      username: "",
      password: ""
    };
  },
  computed: {
    loggedIn() {
      return this.$store.getters.loggedIn;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    login() {
      this.$store
        .dispatch("LOGIN", {
          username: this.username,
          password: this.password
        })
        .then(response => {
          this.$router.push("/addsub");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import { getField, updateField } from 'vuex-map-fields'
import axios from 'axios'

// import example from './module-example'

Vue.use(Vuex)

/*
 * If not building with SSR mode, you can
 * directly export the Store instantiation;
 *
 * The function below can be async too; either use
 * async/await or return a Promise which resolves
 * with the Store instance.
 */

export default function (/* { ssrContext } */) {
  const Store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      // example
    },
    state: {
      token: localStorage.getItem('access_token') || null,
      subData: {
        subjectName: ''
      },
      testItems: {
        testId: '',
        subjectName: '',
        existingTest: '',
        question: '',
        answer: '',
        studentAnswer: ''
      }
    },
    mutations: {
      sendData: state => {
        const config = {
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        }
        axios
          .post(
            'http://localhost/MyComposer/?submitId=0',
            {
              subjectName: state.subData.subjectName
            },
            config
          )
          .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            alert(res.data)
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error.response)
          })
      },
      //FOR TEACHER
      submitTestData: state => {
        const config = {
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        }
        axios
          .post(
            'http://localhost/MyComposer/?submitId=1',
            {
              subjectName: state.testItems.subjectName,
              question: state.testItems.question,
              answer: state.testItems.answer
            },
            config
          )
          .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            alert(res.data)
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error.response)
          })
      },
      //FOR STUDENT
      submitData: state => {
        const config = {
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        }
        axios
          .post(
            'http://localhost/MyComposer/?submitId=2',
            {
              existingTest: state.testItems.existingTest,
              studentAnswer: state.testItems.studentAnswer
            },
            config
          )
          .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            alert(res.data)
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error.response)
          })
      },
      updateField,
      logMeIn (state, token) {
        state.token = token
      },
      destroyToken (state) {
        state.token = null
      }
    },
    getters: {
      getField,
      loggedIn (state) {
        return state.token != null
      }
    },
    actions: {
      LOGIN (context, payload) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          axios
            .post('http://localhost/MyComposer/?submitId=3', payload)
            .then(response => {
              console.log(payload.username)
              console.log(payload.password)
              console.log(response.data)
              console.log(response.data.username)
              console.log(response.data.password)
              for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                if (
                  response.data[i].Username === payload.username &&
                  response.data[i].Password === payload.password
                ) {
                  alert('Logged In Successfully!')
                  console.log(payload)
                  console.log(response.data)
                  resolve(response)

                  const token = response.data[i].UserId
                  console.log(token)
                  localStorage.setItem('access_token', token)
                  context.commit('logMeIn', token)
                }
              }
            })
            .catch(error => {
              reject('Incorrect Username or password. Please try again!')
              console.log(error)
            })
        })
      },
      destroyToken (context) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] =
          'Bearer ' + context.state.token
        if (context.getters.loggedIn) {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios
              .post('http://localhost/MyComposer/')
              .then(response => {
                for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                  if (
                    response.data[i].Username === payload.username &&
                    response.data[i].Password === payload.password
                  ) {
                    alert('Logged In Successfully!')
                    console.log(payload)
                    console.log(response.data)
                    resolve(response)

                    console.log(token)
                    localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
                    context.commit('destroyToken')
                  }
                }
              })
              .catch(error => {
                localStorage.removeItem('data')
                context.commit('destroyToken')
                console.log(error)
              })
          })
        }
      }
    },
    // enable strict mode (adds overhead!)
    // for dev mode only
    strict: process.env.DEV
  })

  return Store
}
```

Router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import routes from './routes'
// import { store } from '../store/index'
import { store } from 'quasar/wrappers'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

/*
 * If not building with SSR mode, you can
 * directly export the Router instantiation;
 *
 * The function below can be async too; either use
 * async/await or return a Promise which resolves
 * with the Router instance.
 */

export default function (/* { store, ssrContext } */) {
  const router = new VueRouter({
    scrollBehavior: () => ({ x: 0, y: 0 }),
    routes,
    store,
    // Leave these as they are and change in quasar.conf.js instead!
    // quasar.conf.js -> build -> vueRouterMode
    // quasar.conf.js -> build -> publicPath
    mode: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE,
    base: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_BASE
  })

  router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
      if (store.getters.loggedIn) {
        next({
          path: '/'
          // query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
        })
      } else {
        next()
      }
    } else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresVisitor)) {
      if (store.getters.loggedIn) {
        next({
          path: '/addsub'
          // query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
        })
      } else {
        next()
      }
    } else {
      next() // make sure to always call next()!
    }
  })

  return router
}
```

routes.js

```
// import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

// const router = new VueRouter({
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/MyLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: () => import('pages/Index.vue')
      },
      {
        path: '/subjectntestlist',
        component: () => import('pages/SubTestList.vue'),
        meta: {
          requiresAuth: true
        }
      },
      {
        path: '/addsub',
        component: () => import('pages/FormData.vue'),
        meta: {
          requiresAuth: true
        }
      },
      {
        path: '/logout',
        component: () => import('pages/Logout.vue'),
        meta: {
          requiresAuth: true
        }
      },
      {
        path: '/register',
        component: () => import('pages/Register.vue'),
        meta: {
          requiresVisitor: true
        }
      },
      {
        path: '/newtest',
        component: () => import('pages/AddTest.vue'),
        meta: {
          requiresAuth: true
        }
      },
      {
        path: '/testlist',
        component: () => import('pages/TestList.vue'),
        meta: {
          requiresAuth: true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
// })

// Always leave this as last one
if (process.env.MODE !== 'ssr') {
  routes.push({
    path: '*',
    component: () => import('pages/Error404.vue')
  })
}

export default routes
```

Comment: Why did you put `store` in a `VueRouter` ? You should put it in a `new Vue({ el, router, store, render})`

Comment: The new Vue doesn't work. It just thinks it's not compatible with the Quasar build.

Comment: OK, I don't know Quasar, but putting `store` in a `Router` looks very strange to me.

Comment: Well, I admit it was a mistake putting it there. But, is my navigation guard code correct? Like the if else condition with the store.getters.loggedIn. It's not Boolean so I tried the punctuation version instead. But the getters isn't retrieving any data. The store is done right since I can see the passed data from Login.

Comment: Finally got it. Thanks for the help. I knew putting the store inside the router gave me an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working. If you're going to work in Quasar, just un-comment out something they made for you, a.k.a. reserved words. I solved my problem by doing so
instead of creating a new Vue component just to call out the store. Also, you don't have to remove the export defaults at all because they are actually very helpful with easier connections with other components.

```
export default function ({ store, ssrContext } /* { store, ssrContext } */) { <-- This was commented out before
  const router = new VueRouter({
    scrollBehavior: () => ({ x: 0, y: 0 }),
    routes,
    // Leave these as they are and change in quasar.conf.js instead!
    // quasar.conf.js -> build -> vueRouterMode
    // quasar.conf.js -> build -> publicPath
    mode: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE,
    base: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_BASE
  })

  router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
      if (!store.getters.loggedIn) {
        next({
          path: '/'
          // query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
        })
      } else {
        next()
      }
    } else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresVisitor)) {
      if (store.getters.loggedIn) {
        next({
          path: '/addsub'
          // query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
        })
      } else {
        next()
      }
    } else {
      next() // make sure to always call next()!
    }
  })

  return router
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the help. This is a rewarding discovery for me.